# Beautiful Soup Scrape not showing properly

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm doing something simple, and the results are not showing up properly.
The website is [Bed Bath & Beyond](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/bed-bath/bedding-accessories/10505/). I'm trying to get product totals per category.

My script looks like this.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/bed-bath/bedding-accessories/10505/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
li = soup.find_all("li", {"class" : "listCount noPadLeft"})
for l in li:
     print(l.text)
```

And is outputting nothing, even though i know there is text in the elements. I just need to get inside one element, but found when that wasn't working to do a find_all instead to try and figure out what was going on.

This is the html of what i am scraping:

```
<li class="listCount noPadLeft">


<strong>Showing&nbsp;   


1 - 48



</strong>   <span>of&nbsp;124&nbsp;product(s)
</span> </li>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know any Python, certainly not familiar with Beautiful Soup.. but to me it looks as if soup contains an Array/Variable with your webpage, you are then asking it to find tags with <li> and assigning those tags to variable li... from there I don't know what .text means.. but finding text between tags you in Javascript you call something like var := li[index].innerText

Answer (score 0):

try this code (python 3):

```
import urllib.request as rq
import bs4
url=rq.urlopen('http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/bed-bath/bedding-accessories/10505/').read().decode('utf-8')
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(url)
a=soup.find_all('li',class_="listCount noPadLeft")
for i in a:
    print(i.text)
```